# How do I convert List<List<Object>> to a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
List<List<Object>> EventAll = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

while(rs1.next())
{
    List<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
    /*EventAll.add(rs1.getRow(), row);*/
    row.add(rs1.getString("eventName")); 
    row.add(rs1.getString("duration")); 
    row.add(rs1.getString("playhead"));
    EventAll.add(row);
}

String[][] stringArray = EventAll.toArray(new String[EventAll.size()][]);//line 66
```

In the above example as you can see I have `List<List<Object>>` and I am adding column values to it in the while loop. It worked fine for me at this point.

But when I tried converting it into multi-dimensional array using `toArray()` method I am getting the following exception:

```
****EXCEPTION:**java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at DataFromMySql.main(DataFromMySql.java:66)**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object[][] array = new Object[EventAll.size()][];

int i = 0;
for (List<Object> event : EventAll) {//each list
    array[i++] = event.toArray(new Object[event.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`toArray` can convert your `List<List<String>>` (you should, BTW, change your `List<List<Object>>` to `List<List<String>>`) to `List<String>[]`, not to a `String[][]`.

It can also convert each inner `List<String>` to a `String[]`.

Therefore, you'll have to create the 2-D array, and initialize each row of that array separately with `EventAll.get(i).toArray(new String[EventAll.get(i).size()])`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this will only work if your inner Lists do have the same length and all Objects are strings!

```
String[][] array = new String[list.size()][list.get(0).size()];
System.out.println();
int i = 0;
for (List<Object> l : list ) {
    int j = 0;
    for (Object obj : l) {
        array[i][j] = (String) obj;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```